# Return To Previous Page - Mobile HTML

Tags: php, html, ratchet-2

I'm building an app with [Ratchet](http://www.goratchet.com), and in the navbar I'd like to use BACK & NEXT buttons.

Now, I'm not using [Ratchet's built-in Push.js](http://goratchet.com/components/#push) due to structural constraints.

Is there a way to create a page-independent BACK & NEXT buttons that look for the corresponding pages in my history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the History API

```
   <header class="bar bar-nav">
      <a class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-left" onclick="window.history.back()">
        <span class="icon icon-left-nav" ></span>
        Left
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-right" onclick="window.history.forward()">
        Right
        <span class="icon icon-right-nav" ></span>
      </a>
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </header>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xae73vvq/1/)